# Cannot be opened because its project type (.dtproj) is not supported by this version of application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis-2008

In my VS 2008 not shown BI Application, but before its supporting Packages, suddenly some changes happened then packages not supported.

"Project type .dtproj is not supported by this version of the application"

[Error shown in visual studio 2008](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebVxz.png)